# Application Insights TelemetryConfiguration.Active

Tags: azure-functions

Can someone help me understand what this property actually does please?

On this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#custom-telemetry-in-c-functions

It clearly states:

```
 private static string key = TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = 
            System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(
                "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

but then, `TelemetryConfiguration` is never used again... the `key` string is, as this is used to set the `InstumentationKey` when creating a `TelemetryClient()` i.e.

```
  private static TelemetryClient telemetryClient = 
            new TelemetryClient() { InstrumentationKey = key };
```

This makes sense, but what does the TelemetryConfiguration do exactly?!

Re: Functions, what i want to do is have a central logging helper class, to which i can have a static TelemetryClient, and then set the following for each function using it...

```
x.Context.Cloud.RoleName = "myRole";
x.Context.Operation.Id = executionContext.InvocationId.ToString();
```

should x be set at a `TelemetryClient` object, or the actual `Telemetry` object being logged..

Ty.

Answer (score 0):

`TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey` is used when you use the default TelemetryClient and not create your own. For example the default one ILogger logs to.

Comment: ok, i think... but in my case do i set the RoleName property on the `TelemetryClient(TelemetryConfiguration.Active)`, or on the `Telemetry` getting logged?